# laravel blade concat property

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
@foreach($variationTypeCollection as $key => $var)

do some thing

@foreach($collection as $col)

{{ $col->variationId.$key++ }}

@endforeach

@endforeach
```

How to concat property with the key

I want it look like variationId1, variationId2

Thank you.

Comment: Your code should work just fine, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: It say "Undefined property: stdClass::$variationId"

Comment: Go back in your controller and check whether you are getting a variationId value not.

Comment: Try `{{ $col->{'variationId' . $key++'} }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@foreach($collection as $col)

    {{ $col->{'variationId' . $key++ } }}

@endforeach
```

for more readability

```
@foreach($collection as $col)

    @php($property = 'variationId' . $key++) 
    {{ $col->{$property} }}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($collection as $col)

{{ $col->variationId }}{{ $loop->iteration }}

@endforeach
```

This might solve your problem